# Bullseye Coverage Behaviour with relative COVFILE

Tags: code-coverage, bullseye

I have a problem with Bullseye Coverage when using relative COVFILES (or default without COVFILE set).

It seems like the coverage result is different when using individual COVFILES and `covmerge` instead of COVFILE set to an absolute path. The coverage for single files merged is measured much lower.

Is there a known issue?